# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)f(x)dx=?$

Tags: limits, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(x) \sin ((2n+1) x) dx =0 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175413/how-can-i-prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-pi-2-fx-sin-2n1-x-dx-0)

I have trouble evaluating the following limit?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)f(x)dx
$$
for any square integrable function $f(x)$.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175413/how-can-i-prove-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-pi-2-fx-sin-2n1-x-dx-0?rq=1).

Comment: Also, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/question-on-weak-convergence-example). If I kept searching, I'm sure I could find others...

Comment: This follows from the [Riemann–Lebesgue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Lebesgue_lemma) lemma.